# How to maintain a user model in API.AI (Dialogflow) for a chatbot

Tags: chatbot, dialogflow-es

I am using Dialogflow to create a chat bot. How do I maintain a user model within a chatbot system?

I want to have a different user model saved for each user in a group. The user model should store the user’s name, personal information it gathers from the dialog, and the user’s likes and dislikes.

With this information, I would like to add personalized remarks from the user model to the dialog engine.

Answer (score 3):

You need some database to story User information.

as per Dialogflow

> It's helpful to think of API.AI as just that - an API that you use to
>   parse user intent from natural language queries. If you have custom
>   business logic, platform-specific formatting requirements, or need to
>   integrate with external data stores, it would be better to create your
>   bot from scratch in code, and make calls out to API.AI in order to
>   parse inbound queries. API.AI isn't a bot-building platform, but a
>   Natural Language Understanding platform.

for more Information [click here](https://discuss.api.ai/t/can-api-ai-ask-my-database-for-info-before-asking-user/1870/3)

you can use web-hooks which hits your controller function and run logics which you want like save information.There is one Object like `response` in which all information inside there

Answer (score 0):

It depends how long you wish to maintain the information about the user and what platform, if any, you're integrating Dashbot with.

Using just the Dashbot framework, one good way to maintain the user information is through the parameters available to a [Context](https://dialogflow.com/docs/contexts). This will be retained during the entire conversational session.

However, if you want to maintain this information between sessions, you'll need to handle this in your fulfillment - in particular, you'll have to save it in a permanent store (such as a database) against a userid if one is provided for your integration.

Comment: I am integrating it on "web demo". I only want to maintain it for session

Comment: Then, as noted in the answer, a Context might work well for you.

Comment: Is there an example?